Error deploying ELK on kubernetes
I was following the Elasticsearch documentation (Deploy an Elasticsearch cluster | Elastic Cloud on Kubernetes [2.14] | Elastic)
I am getting the below error while deploying the elasticsearch cluster on kubernetes:

Defaulted container "elasticsearch" out of: elasticsearch,
elastic-internal-init-filesystem (init), elastic-internal-suspend
(init) java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:
/usr/share/elasticsearch/data at
java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
at
java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.asIOException(UnixException.java:115)
at
java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:477)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:481) at
java.base/java.nio.file.Files.list(Files.java:3777) at
org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.cli.AutoConfigureNode.isDirEmpty(AutoConfigureNode.java:1151)
at
org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.cli.AutoConfigureNode.execute(AutoConfigureNode.java:166)
at
org.elasticsearch.server.cli.ServerCli.autoConfigureSecurity(ServerCli.java:174)
at org.elasticsearch.server.cli.ServerCli.execute(ServerCli.java:87)
at
org.elasticsearch.common.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:54)
at
org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:94)
at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:51) at
org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher.main(CliToolLauncher.java:64)

Any suggestion would be appreciated
thanks

Please, Could you specify the version that you are trying to use?

@c4f4t0r. it is 8.15.2

Are you mapping any external file into a docker container?
